# Openpyxl format excel chart background

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

Does anyone know if it is possible to format a chart background and border using openpyxl? I can do this relatively easily in xlsxwriter (see below for examples), but cannot determine how to do it or if it is possible in openpyxl. Any ideas?

Thanks!

xlsxwriter format example:

```
chart1.set_chartarea({
    'border': {'color': 'white'}})

chart1.set_plotarea({
    'layout': {
        'x':      0.16,
        'y':      0.15,
        'width':  0.75,
        'height': 0.55
    },
    'fill': 
        {'color': '#eeece1'} })
```